# Is there a Windows 10 PowerShell equivalent to .bashrc for Linux Bash?

Tags: bash, powershell, windows-10

I want to run some commands by default every time I open up power shell. Bash has a .bashrc file that it runs as source when it starts up. Is there a way to do this with powershell?

Comment: They're called "powershell profiles": https://superuser.com/questions/1090141/does-powershell-have-any-sort-of-bashrc-equivalent

Comment: Thank you @Dai .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As pointed out by Dai in the comment section, [Powershell Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7) sound like the closest equivalent to the `.bashrc` file.

> A PowerShell profile is a script that runs when PowerShell starts. You can use the profile as a logon script to customize the environment. You can add commands, aliases, functions, variables, snap-ins, modules, and PowerShell drives. You can also add other session-specific elements to your profile so they are available in every session without having to import or re-create them.