# Invoke a JavaScript or Node.js program using an alias

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, alias

I am writing a JavaScript program that needs to invoked on the command line using a special command/alias. Instead of typing `node fileName.js`, I need to be able to just type `newFile` to run it. My understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) is that I could create a Bash script to run the JavaScript and use an alias to run that. But I would like to avoid using a Bash script if I can.

I looked into Node to see if I can do this. All I found was information about putting the name of the program in the package.json file, as a value for "start", under "scripts." But then to run the program I would have to type `npm start`. I looked for a way that I could create an alias for `npm start` within Node itself, but I didn't find one.

Is there a way to do what I want, with or without Node, without using an external script?

Comment: [How to Create Bash Aliases](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/)

Comment: You can install the package globally as a cli with npm.  Numerous examples available online.  e.g.:  https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/18/command-line-app-with-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

No you can't... It might possible with shell script.
But in your machine node js run with help of npm.

Every javascript project has a package.json file which is managed package file for your project. So you can not do what you want.

What I suggest:
Use nodemon.

```
npm i nodemon
```

then in package.json
add another script "dev" or whatever you want or you can write under start script.

```
"dev":"nodemon app.js",
```

Then everytime you save your application your server will restart automatically

> **Note:** Each time you copy or select something from command prompt while using nodemon; dont forge to press **rs**

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define aliases for the commands we use to execute scripts in interpreted languages such as JavaScript and Python, but it depends on the operating system and terminal we are using:

- In Linux, we can use the following syntax in the Bash shell to define an alias:

  ```bash
  alias <alias>='<command>'
  ```

  Examples:

  - Defining an alias that executes a JavaScript script:

    ```bash
    alias app='<node /path/to/app.js>'
    ```
  - Defining an alias that executes a Python script:

    ```bash
    alias app='<python /path/to/app.py>'
    ```

  [Click here](https://www.tecmint.com/create-alias-in-linux/) and [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-permanent-bash-alias-linux-unix/) to learn more about the `alias` command in the Bash shell and how to make it permanent.
- In Windows, we can use the following syntax in PowerShell to define an alias:

  ```
  function <function-name> {<command>}
  set-alias -name <alias> -value <function-name>
  ```

  Examples:

  - Defining an alias that executes a JavaScript script:

    ```
    function app-aux {node /path/to/app.js $args}
    set-alias -name app -value app-aux
    ```
  - Defining an alias that executes a Python script:

    ```
    function app-aux {python /path/to/app.py $args}
    set-alias -name app -value app-aux
    ```

  [Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.3#example-5-create-an-alias-for-a-command-with-parameters) to learn more about the `set-alias` command in PowerShell. To make the alias permanent in PowerShell, there is an equivalent to `.bashrc`, which is the `Profile.ps1` file. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175669/is-there-a-windows-10-powershell-equivalent-to-bashrc-for-linux-bash) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3) to learn more.

Comment: Naming what or who you are referencing makes it clearer and nicer to read in comparison to a generic `here` or `Click here`.