# Standard way to achieve the 'bashrc.d' mechanism equivalent in PowerShell Profile

Tags: powershell

As you can see in many articles<sup>[1](https://byparker.com/blog/2021/the-power-of-bashrc-d/)</sup> <sup>[2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjm8b7jqtz_AhUN_SoKHV_WDdgQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwaxzce.medium.com%2Fuse-bashrc-d-directory-instead-of-bloated-bashrc-50204d5389ff&usg=AOvVaw25psDW3kysWmrIZIyFNqKu&opi=89978449)</sup> in the Linux world, say when you want to add some configurations or add some plugin in the *[.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)* file, it is much better to add in *bashrc.d* to achieve more maintainability.

So as you know in the PowerShell world, we have the equivalent<sup>[4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59829043/1539100)</sup> of *.bashrc*. That is the [PowerShell Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3). But my problem is I could not find any equivalent for *bashrc.d* that I can very simply add configuration files and load automatically in the profile and override profile values based on alphabetically order.

What is the *standard* way to achieve the *bashrc.d* mechanism equivalent in PowerShell Profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a made-up construct, *[Use .bashrc.d directory instead of bloated .bashrc](https://waxzce.medium.com/use-bashrc-d-directory-instead-of-bloated-bashrc-50204d5389ff)*, so the equivalent in PowerShell would be in $profile:

```
foreach($file in dir ~/.psrc.d/*.ps1) { . $file }
```

The files have to end in .ps1.

Comment: Is there exist any official and standard way to achieve this? or we must to add some custom code to profile as you say?

Comment: @sorosh_sabz Even unix doesn't have an official way.